# Does using val with Hashtable in Scala resolve concurrency issues?

Tags: scala

I try to avoid vars in my code where possible for easier multithreading.  However there is one line of code that starts:

```
val positions: Hashtable[String, String] ...
```

I'm wondering does the val make things automagically thread safe or are there further details that I need to worry about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By prefixing `positions` with a `val` you make it immutable. By "it" I mean the reference to the `Hashtable` and not the `Hashtable` itself and therefore by "immutable" I mean you cannot assign another `Hashtable` to `positions`.

So the `Hashtable` itself can change over time, but `positions` will always point to it. Nothing is automagically threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which collection type you import. There's `immutable.HashMap` and `mutable.HashMap`. So `immutable.HashMap` in combination with a val reference would be the right one to use. That does not necessarily mean everything's threadsafe now, however.

Answer (score 1):

The code from Joshua Suereth’s book ‘Scala in Depth’ posted by Jan van der Vorst is helpful as long as you don’t need to guarantee that the calls to lookUp always return the latest data. It is not appropriate if you need lookUp always to work with the latest data added by insert. For more information, please see Joshua Suereth’s comments on this discussion:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-user/ORxWFIzRb2c/discussion

Answer (score 0):

You make things thread safe by synchronizing access to mutable state by using the *synchronized* keyword to the methods in which you access mutable state. If your hashtable is mutable you should synchronize both read and write methods. However, if you know that you will more frequently read than write you might better be using an immutable hashtable with a var position and only synchronize on the write. E.g. copied from the excellent book "Scala in Depth" by Joshua D. Suereth:

```
class ImmutableService[Key, Value] extends Service[Key, Value] {
  var currentIndex = new ImmutableHashMap[Key,Value]
  def lookUp(k : Key) : Option[Value] = currentIndex.get(k)
  def insert(k : Key, v: Value) : Unit = synchronized {
    currentIndex = currentIndex + ((k, v))
  }
}
```