# In Scala, what does "extends (A => B)" on a case class mean?

Tags: scala, dictionary, memoization

In researching how to do Memoization in Scala, I've found some code I didn't grok. I've tried to look this particular "thing" up, but don't know by what to call it; i.e. the term by which to refer to it. Additionally, it's not easy searching using a symbol, ugh!

I saw the following code to do memoization in Scala [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257378/is-there-a-generic-way-to-memoize-in-scala):

```
case class Memo[A,B](f: A => B) extends (A => B) {
  private val cache = mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
  def apply(x: A) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}
```

And it's what the case class is extending that is confusing me, the `extends (A => B)` part. First, what is happening? Secondly, why is it even needed? And finally, what do you call this kind of inheritance; i.e. is there some specific name or term I can use to refer to it?

Next, I am seeing Memo used in this way to calculate a Fibanocci number [here](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/Combinatorics.scala):

```
  val fibonacci: Memo[Int, BigInt] = Memo {
    case 0 => 0
    case 1 => 1
    case n => fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
  }
```

It's probably my not seeing all of the "simplifications" that are being applied. But, I am not able to figure out the end of the `val` line, `= Memo {`. So, if this was typed out more verbosely, perhaps I would understand the "leap" being made as to how the Memo is being constructed.

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: More clarification posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129721/how-does-this-scala-memo-works/25129872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a synthesis of the partial answers provided by both 0__ and Nicolas Rinaudo.

**Summary:**

There are many convenient (but also highly intertwined) assumptions being made by the Scala compiler.

1. Scala treats `extends (A => B)` as synonymous with `extends Function1[A, B]` ([ScalaDoc for Function1[+T1, -R]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1))
2. A concrete implementation of Function1's inherited abstract method `apply(x: A): B` must be provided; `def apply(x: A): B = cache.getOrElseUpdate(x, f(x))`
3. Scala assumes an implied `match` for the code block starting with `= Memo {`
4. Scala passes the content between `{}` started in item 3 as a parameter to the Memo case class constructor
5. Scala assumes an implied type between `{}` started in item 3 as `PartialFunction[Int, BigInt]` and the compiler uses the "match" code block as the override for the PartialFunction method's `apply()` and then provides an additional override for the PartialFunction's method `isDefinedAt()`.

**Details:**

The first code block defining the case class Memo can be written more verbosely as such:

```
case class Memo[A,B](f: A => B) extends Function1[A, B] {    //replaced (A => B) with what it's translated to mean by the Scala compiler
  private val cache = mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
  def apply(x: A): B = cache.getOrElseUpdate(x, f(x))  //concrete implementation of unimplemented method defined in parent class, Function1
}
```

The second code block defining the val fibanocci can be written more verbosely as such:

```
lazy val fibonacci: Memo[Int, BigInt] = {
  Memo.apply(
    new PartialFunction[Int, BigInt] {
      override def apply(x: Int): BigInt = {
        x match {
          case 0 => 0
          case 1 => 1
          case n => fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
        }
      }
      override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = true
    }
  )
}
```

Had to add `lazy` to the second code block's val in order to deal with a self-referential problem in the line `case n => fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)`.

And finally, an example usage of fibonacci is:

```
val x:BigInt = fibonacci(20) //returns 6765 (almost instantly)
```

Comment: I believe your `2.` is not needed (nor really correct), since `override` is an annotation that you add to help the compiler but is never required nor present in the compiler's output. Your `3.` is slightly wrong: there is no implied match - `a match {...` just means that the partial function is called with argument `a`, and in our case, it's passed as a parameter, not called. `4.` is a simplification: the partial function is passed to the `apply` method of the companion object, which *then* passes it to the constructor. You're 100% correct about the `lazy`, apologies for the oversight.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo My purpose is to show all the assumptions being made by being over-verbose; i.e. use as few of the compiler simplifications as possible. Hence, my using "override" in item 2. BTW, I think "override" is only _optional_ when the override is to an abstract method. It is required when overriding a non-abstract method, right?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Per item 3, again I am attempting to show assumption leaps being made by the compiler simplifications. So, I am intentionally being Java level verbose with types. So, given what I have read numerous places, the PartialFunction being produced is from the compiler converting the match (i.e. the block of case statements) into a PartialFunction. Are you saying this is not what is happening?

Comment: Regarding `override`: you're right, it's required in some cases, just not this one. I feel that stating the compiler assumes its presence is not correct, but it's a matter of perspective. As for `match`, my understanding is that `a match {…}` generates a function and immediately applies it to `a` - which is not what happens in your case, a function *is* generated but not applied. Feel free to explain it however you feel comfortable with, I just do not think it's an accurate description of what actually happens. I've been known to be wrong, though.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo Ah! I get what you are distinguishing. It's not an immediately executed function. But, isn't that why it's inside of a PartialFunction? IOW, while it appears to be immediately evaluated in the apply(), the apply() itself won't be executed until later; i.e. when the PartialFunction instance is used, thereby giving the delayed execution I think you are describing. Am I missing something? If so, could you suggest how I could rewrite it such that it is both an explicit match and it is delay executed?

Comment: #2 should really be: because it extends `Function1[A, B]` it must provide a concrete `def apply(a: A): B`

Comment: @sourcedelica Tysvm! I have updated my answer to accommodate your recommendation.

Answer (score 16):

`A => B` is short for `Function1[A, B]`, so your `Memo` extends a function from `A` to `B`, most prominently defined through method `apply(x: A): B` which must be defined.

Because of the "infix" notation, you need to put parentheses around the type, i.e. `(A => B)`. You could also write

```
case class Memo[A, B](f: A => B) extends Function1[A, B] ...
```

or

```
case class Memo[A, B](f: Function1[A, B]) extends Function1[A, B] ...
```

Comment: Awesome! So, I think you are saying the Scala compiler is converting "extends (A => B)" to "extends Function[A, B]". And Function[A, B] is a class (or trait?) already defined somewhere in Scala's default libraries. And Function[A, B] has an defined function "def apply(x: A): B" which is abstract; i.e. provides no implementation which must be overridden. Is that all correct? Then, is there a name for this class of "extends"? And then what is happening, more explicitly, in the second bit of code using the Memo?

Comment: Yes, this is just an alternative syntax.

Comment: I've created an answer that incorporated your information. If/when you get a chance, could you please look it over to ensure I caught everything you provided just in case I might have missed some subtlety that's beyond me? Ty.

Answer (score 7):

To complete 0_'s answer, `fibonacci` is being instanciated through the apply method of `Memo`'s companion object, generated automatically by the compiler since `Memo` is a case class.

This means that the following code is generated for you:

```
object Memo {
  def apply[A, B](f: A => B): Memo[A, B] = new Memo(f)
}
```

Scala has special handling for the `apply` method: its name needs not be typed when calling it. The two following calls are strictly equivalent:

```
Memo((a: Int) => a * 2)

Memo.apply((a: Int) => a * 2)
```

The `case` block is known as pattern matching. Under the hood, it generates a partial function - that is, a function that is defined for some of its input parameters, but not necessarily all of them. I'll not go in the details of partial functions as it's beside the point ([this](http://nrinaudo.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/partial-functions/) is a memo I wrote to myself on that topic, if you're keen), but what it essentially means here is that the `case` block is in fact an instance of [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction).

If you follow that link, you'll see that `PartialFunction` extends [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1) - which is the expected argument of `Memo.apply`.

So what that bit of code actually means, once desugared (if that's a word), is:

```
lazy val fibonacci: Memo[Int, BigInt] = Memo.apply(new PartialFunction[Int, BigInt] {
  override def apply(v: Int): Int =
    if(v == 0)      0
    else if(v == 1) 1
    else            fibonacci(v - 1) + fibonacci(v - 2)

  override isDefinedAt(v: Int) = true
})
```

Note that I've vastly simplified the way the pattern matching is handled, but I thought that starting a discussion about `unapply` and `unapplySeq` would be off topic and confusing.

Comment: I got everything right up and until your last sentence, "The pattern-matching passed to apply is a PartialFunction1, which is an instance of Function1." And there, you lost me. There still appears to be too much assumed about the "= Memo {...}" part; i.e. too many Scala syntax reductions where I am not able to make the "assumption leaps".

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium now that I have access to a proper computer, I've added proper code samples to my explanation. I hope this clarifies things for you, even though _0's answer really is the one you were looking for.

Comment: Good, thorough explanation.  The question does have two parts so really you and 0__ both deserve credit.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo - Tyvm. So, there were several types and layers of intertwined assumptions. And I am good with the match itself (i.e. pattern matching). It was that the Scala compiler makes another "assumption" leap regarding the pattern match to define it as a PartialFunction that got me.

Comment: To create a single answer pulling everything together, I just created an answer after verifying everything in the Eclipse Scala-IDE.

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo If/when you get a chance, would you validate my answer is properly incorporating your points? It checks out in Eclipse's ScalaIDE's WorkSheet. I just want to make sure I didn't miss some subtlety that's beyond me.

Comment: Your assumptions about `PartialFunction` are wrong, there is no `PartialFunction` created. In fact those are only created if the compiler is explicitly told so, for example with `case class Memo[A,B](f: PartialFunction[A,B])`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just checked and the decompiled code creates an `AbstractFunction1`, not a `PartialFunction`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

I am the [original](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/DynamicProgramming.scala#L15) author of doing memoization this way. You can see some sample usages in that same file. It also works really well when you want to memoize on multiple arguments too because of the way Scala unrolls tuples:

```
    /**
     * @return memoized function to calculate C(n,r) 
     * see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html
     */
     val c: Memo[(Int, Int), BigInt] = Memo {
        case (_, 0) => 1
        case (n, r) if r > n/2 => c(n, n-r)
        case (n, r) => c(n-1, r-1) + c(n-1, r)
     }
     // note how I can invoke a memoized function on multiple args too
     val x = c(10, 3)
```

Comment: Tyvm for posting that. I loved what you had done, but couldn't grok all the ways you were leveraging the hell out of Scala, LOL! Hence, this question. :)

Comment: I have since then created a standlaone Memo.scala: https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/Memo.scala

Simple usage:
https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/Combinatorics.scala#L84-L91

Complex usage:
https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/DynamicProgramming.scala#L14-L33

Answer (score 2):

One more word about this `extends (A => B)`: the `extends` here is not required, but necessary if the instances of `Memo` are to be used in higher order functions or situations alike.

Without this `extends (A => B)`, it's totally fine if you use the `Memo` instance `fibonacci` in just method calls.

```
case class Memo[A,B](f: A => B) {
    private val cache = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[A, B]
    def apply(x: A):B = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}
val fibonacci: Memo[Int, BigInt] = Memo {
    case 0 => 0
    case 1 => 1
    case n => fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
}
```

For example:

```
Scala> fibonacci(30)
res1: BigInt = 832040
```

But when you want to use it in higher order functions, you'd have a type mismatch error.

```
Scala> Range(1, 10).map(fibonacci)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Memo[Int,BigInt]
 required: Int => ?
              Range(1, 10).map(fibonacci)
                               ^
```

So the `extends` here only helps to ID the instance `fibonacci` to others that it has an `apply` method and thus can do some jobs.