# Scala Memoization: How does this Scala memo work?

Tags: scala, dynamic-programming, memoization

The following code is from [Pathikrit's Dynamic Programming](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/DynamicProgramming.scala#L44-L55) repository.
I'm mystified by both its beauty and peculiarity.

```
def subsetSum(s: List[Int], t: Int) = {
  type DP = Memo[(List[Int], Int), (Int, Int), Seq[Seq[Int]]]
  implicit def encode(key: (List[Int], Int)) = (key._1.length, key._2)

  lazy val f: DP = Memo {
    case (Nil, 0) => Seq(Nil)
    case (Nil, _) => Nil
    case (a :: as, x) => (f(as, x - a) map {_ :+ a}) ++ f(as, x)
  }

  f(s, t)
}
```

The type `Memo` is implemented in another file:

```
case class Memo[I <% K, K, O](f: I => O) extends (I => O) {
  import collection.mutable.{Map => Dict}
  val cache = Dict.empty[K, O]
  override def apply(x: I) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is `type K` declared as `(Int, Int)` in subsetSum?
2. What does the `int` in `(Int, Int)` stand for respectively?

<strike>3. How does `(List[Int], Int)` implicitly convert to `(Int, Int)`?

I see no `implicit def foo(x:(List[Int],Int)) = (x._1.toInt,x._2)`.  ( not even in the `Implicits.scala` file it imports.</strike>

*Edit: Well, I miss this:

```
implicit def encode(key: (List[Int], Int)) = (key._1.length, key._2)
```

I enjoy Pathikrit's library [scalgos](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos) very much.  There are a lot of Scala pearls in it.  Please help me with this so I can appreciate Pathikrit's wit.  Thank you.  (:

Comment: Regarding #3, you forgot to read the line with `implicit def encode`

Comment: I've seen the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257378/is-there-a-generic-way-to-memoize-in-scala), but I still wonder **does value `f` really memoize**?  It seems that every time `subsetSum` is called, a new instance of Memo is created and it is not the last memo we want.  Is it true?

Comment: Yes, for a given `s`, `t`, it returns a `Memo` object. further calls on that `Memo` object would be `O(1)` if it was computed before. You can convince yourself by writing a simple fibonacci memoized function e.g.

    lazy val factorial: Int ==> BigInt = Memo {
      case 0 => 1
      case n => n * factorial(n - 1)
    }

Comment: Another way to convince yourself is to put this line in `Memo.scala`:

cache getOrElseUpdate (x, (y) => println(s"Cache miss: $y"); f(y))

Comment: @wrick  **See [here](https://gist.github.com/IthacaCow/609ba7defbe0549ef002)**  This is the testing result.  Memo doesn't seem to work....

Comment: There is a difference between returning the computed value using dynamic programming i.e. `f(s, t)` versus return the dynamic program (aka memoized closure over `s` and `t`) i.e. returning `f` itself. See my reply to you [here](https://gist.github.com/IthacaCow/609ba7defbe0549ef002)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation.  Now I totally understand all the mechanism. You're kind (:

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I am the author of the [above code](https://github.com/pathikrit/scalgos/blob/7ded867ba39c54011f03bf37a6ff845b020476ff/src/main/scala/com/github/pathikrit/scalgos/Memo.scala).

```
/**
 * Generic way to create memoized functions (even recursive and multiple-arg ones)
 *
 * @param f the function to memoize
 * @tparam I input to f
 * @tparam K the keys we should use in cache instead of I
 * @tparam O output of f
 */
case class Memo[I <% K, K, O](f: I => O) extends (I => O) {
  import collection.mutable.{Map => Dict}
  type Input = I
  type Key = K
  type Output = O
  val cache = Dict.empty[K, O]
  override def apply(x: I) = cache getOrElseUpdate (x, f(x))
}

object Memo {
  /**
   * Type of a simple memoized function e.g. when I = K
   */
  type ==>[I, O] = Memo[I, I, O]
}
```

In `Memo[I <% K, K, O]`:

```
I: input
K: key to lookup in cache
O: output
```

The line `I <% K` means the `K` can be [viewable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds) (i.e. implicitly converted) from `I`.

In most cases, `I` should be `K` e.g. if you are writing `fibonacci` which is a function of type `Int => Int`, it is okay to cache by `Int` itself.

But, sometimes when you are writing memoization, you do not want to always memoize or cache by the input itself (`I`) but rather a function of the input (`K`) e.g when you are writing the `subsetSum` algorithm which has input of type `(List[Int], Int)`, you do not want to use `List[Int]` as the key in your cache but rather you want use `List[Int].size` as the part of the key in your cache.

So, here's a concrete case:

```
/**
 * Subset sum algorithm - can we achieve sum t using elements from s?
 * O(s.map(abs).sum * s.length)
 *
 * @param s set of integers
 * @param t target
 * @return true iff there exists a subset of s that sums to t
 */
 def isSubsetSumAchievable(s: List[Int], t: Int): Boolean = {
    type I = (List[Int], Int)     // input type
    type K = (Int, Int)           // cache key i.e. (list.size, int)
    type O = Boolean              // output type      

    type DP = Memo[I, K, O]

    // encode the input as a key in the cache i.e. make K implicitly convertible from I
    implicit def encode(input: DP#Input): DP#Key = (input._1.length, input._2)   

    lazy val f: DP = Memo {
      case (Nil, x) => x == 0      // an empty sequence can only achieve a sum of zero
      case (a :: as, x) => f(as, x - a) || f(as, x)      // try with/without a.head
    }

    f(s, t)
 }
```

You can ofcourse shorten all these into a single line:
`type DP = Memo[(List[Int], Int), (Int, Int), Boolean]`

For the common case (when `I = K`), you can simply do this: `type ==>[I, O] = Memo[I, I, O]`
and use it like this to [calculate the binomial coeff](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) with recursive memoization:

```
  /**
   * http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html
   * @return memoized function to calculate C(n,r)
   */
  val c: (Int, Int) ==> BigInt = Memo {
    case (_, 0) => 1
    case (n, r) if r > n/2 => c(n, n - r)
    case (n, r) => c(n - 1, r - 1) + c(n - 1, r)
  }
```

**To see details how above syntax works, please [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548103/in-scala-what-does-extends-a-b-on-a-case-class-mean).**

Here is a full example which calculates [editDistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) by encoding both the parameters of the input `(Seq, Seq)` to `(Seq.length, Seq.length)`:

```
 /**
   * Calculate edit distance between 2 sequences
   * O(s1.length * s2.length)
   *
   * @return Minimum cost to convert s1 into s2 using delete, insert and replace operations
   */
  def editDistance[A](s1: Seq[A], s2: Seq[A]) = {

    type DP = Memo[(Seq[A], Seq[A]), (Int, Int), Int]
    implicit def encode(key: DP#Input): DP#Key = (key._1.length, key._2.length)

    lazy val f: DP = Memo {
      case (a, Nil) => a.length
      case (Nil, b) => b.length
      case (a :: as, b :: bs) if a == b => f(as, bs)
      case (a, b) => 1 + (f(a, b.tail) min f(a.tail, b) min f(a.tail, b.tail))
    }

    f(s1, s2)
  }
```

And lastly, the canonical fibonacci example:

```
lazy val fib: Int ==> BigInt = Memo {
  case 0 => 0
  case 1 => 1
  case n if n > 1 => fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}

println(fib(100))
```

Comment: Very nice work. Just one thing: `case class` should not be used here given `Memo` contains a member with moving hash.

Comment: Where can I find something about `==>` notation?

Comment: @Krever: Look at the line: `type ==>[I, O] = Memo[I, I, O]` In general these things are called `infix types`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200380/

Comment: why do you use lazy, e.g. in `lazy val f: DP = Memo {...}` ?

Comment: @ipburbank: Because `f` references itself in its own definition.

Comment: Beautiful implementation, so simple, with such a nice syntax. I learnt a few things on Scala just reading these few lines. Thanks :p

Comment: Note that view bounds are deprecated now https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629

Comment: @pathikrit, why not use `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap`?

Comment: Or have `Memo` parameterized by type of `Map` to be used?