# How do you memoization with cases in Scala?

Tags: scala, dynamic-programming, memoization

What is the best way to convert this code which uses memoization into proper Scala using cases and functional programming?

```
def uniquePathsMemoization(n:Int, m:Int, row:Int, col:Int, seen:Array[Array[Int]]):Int = {
  if (row == m && col == n) 1
  if (row > m || col > n) 0

  if (seen(row+1)(col) == -1) seen(row+1)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n, m, row + 1, col, seen)
  if (seen(row)(col + 1) == -1 ) seen(row)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n,m, row, col + 1, seen)

seen(row+1)(col) + seen(row)(col + 1)
}
```

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129721/scala-memoization-how-does-this-scala-memo-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified version of your code that uses `match` and `case`

```
def uniquePathsMemoization(n:Int, m:Int, row:Int, col:Int, seen:Array[Array[Int]]):Int = (row,col) match{

  case (row,col) if row == m && col == n =>
    1
  case (row,col) if row > m || col > n =>
    0
  case (row,col) =>
    if (seen(row+1)(col) == -1) seen(row+1)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n, m, row + 1, col, seen)
    if (seen(row)(col + 1) == -1 ) seen(row)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n,m, row, col + 1, seen)

    seen(row+1)(col) + seen(row)(col + 1)
}
```

It is not easy to convert this code to a pure functional version, due to the state stored in the `seen` array. But this state can be hidden for the rest of the application, using a function decorator:

```
def uniquePathsMemoizationGenerator( maxRows: Int, maxCols:Int ) : (Int,Int,Int,Int) => Int = {


  def uniquePathsMemoization(n:Int, m:Int, row:Int, col:Int, seen:Array[Array[Int]]):Int = (row,col) match{

    case (row,col) if row == m && col == n =>
      1
    case (row,col) if row > m || col > n =>
      0
    case (row,col) =>
      if (seen(row+1)(col) == -1) seen(row+1)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n, m, row + 1, col, seen)
      if (seen(row)(col + 1) == -1 ) seen(row)(col) = uniquePathsMemoization(n,m, row, col + 1, seen)

      seen(row+1)(col) + seen(row)(col + 1)
  }

  val seen = Array.fill(maxRows,maxCols)(-1)
  uniquePathsMemoization(_,_,_,_,seen)
}

val maxRows = ???
val maxCols = ???
val uniquePaths = uniquePathsMemoizationGenerator( maxRows, maxCols )

// Use uniquePaths from this point, instead of uniquePathsMemoization
```